# Python OpenCV: blur image edges after overlaying

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy-ndarray

Python OpenCV: blur image edges after overlaying

Hello, faced such problem: I have an image of nose which I want to overlay in another image. It looks so unnatural because of "sharp" angles and no gradual transition.

The method I have tried blurs edges only inside the nose picture, but I need total blur of whole edges, even outside the picture. First photo is without blur function, and second one is with it. Please help, how to blur whole edges, both inside and outside the nose image?
[without blur function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcnK2.jpg) [blured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY2Fe.jpg)

```
    def blur_image_edge(self, image: numpy.ndarray) -> numpy.ndarray:
        blurred_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (21, 21), 0)
        mask = numpy.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype=numpy.uint8)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255), 5)

        result = numpy.where(mask[..., numpy.newaxis] > 0, blurred_img, image)

        return result
```

Comment: you probably need alpha blending to get what you describe

Comment: Can you give me a small example, please?

Comment: Do you have the images before overlay? Can you please post a reproducible code sample - include reading the input images (include the import statements)?

Comment: @Rotem Sure, here is a code sample: [link](https://pastebin.com/NNiNapcW)
Just put it in one folder with these 2 pictures:
[image 1](https://ibb.co/LrGgzbg)
[image 2](https://ibb.co/kGvBWNz) and run the file

Comment: You suppose to edit your question and post a minimal reproducible code sample. Think about it in your next question (I am not going to try answering this one). I think you may try using `cv2.seamlessClone` as in the [following example](https://learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/).

Comment: you need to make a blend mask which is basically the alpha layer of the top image (white where you want only the top image, and black where you want only the background image). multiply the foreground by the mask, multiply the background by the inverse of the mask, and add the two results together: https://learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Comment: @Rotem cv2.seamlessClone worked in my case, thank you